# How to populate rows in excel based on value and combobox selection using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

I am a beginner with VBA and I have a schedule (screenshot below) that i am trying to alter using a userform.

I have a Userform with 3 comboboxes, 1 for the type of procedure to be performed and then 1 for the start time and another for the end time (these times are based off the first row in the screenshot).

[image]

I want to essentially alter the spreadsheet for a specific procedure using the userform. For example, lets say i want to change procedure 7 to last from 2:00 until 19:00. In a case like that then i would want to see all the rows that have 7 in them to be filled in with 7 under those columns (see result screenshot)

[image]

All i have is code to find which rows contain a certain value and then that value is offset... but i honestly dont know where to go from here... Any help is greated appreciated!!!

```
Dim c As Range
Dim firstAddress As String

Count = 7

With Sheet49.Range("AA7:AA636")
    Set c = .Find(7, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = c.Address
        Do While Not c Is Nothing
            Count = Count + 1
            c.Offset(, -8).Value = c.Value
            Set c = .FindNext(c)
            If Count = 636 Then
            Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    End If
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want to change procedure 7 to last from 2:00 until 19:00. In a case like that then i would want to see all the rows that have 7 in them to be filled in with 7 under those columns

**Logic:**

1. Find the start and end time columns
2. Find the relevant procedure and then fill the entire range in 1 go!

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ColA As Long, ColB As Long
    Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range
    Dim i As Long
    
    '~~> I am hardcoding these values. Pick them up from combobox
    Dim ProcToFind As Long: ProcToFind = 7
    Dim StartTime As String: StartTime = "2:00"
    Dim EndTime As String: EndTime = "19:00"
    
    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = Sheet1
    
    With ws
        '~~> Find the start and end time columns
        '~~> Hardcoded 21. Replace with last column
        For i = 1 To 21
            Select Case TimeValue(Format(.Cells(1, i).Value, "hh:mm:ss"))
                Case TimeValue(StartTime): ColA = i
                Case TimeValue(EndTime): ColB = i
            End Select
        Next i
        
        If ColA = 0 Or ColB = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Unable to find start or end time column(s)"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        Set aCell = .Cells.Find(What:=ProcToFind, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            Set bCell = aCell
            
            '~~> Fill the entire range in 1 go
            .Range(.Cells(aCell.Row, ColA), .Cells(aCell.Row, ColB)).Value = ProcToFind
            
            Do
                Set aCell = .Cells.FindNext(After:=aCell)

                If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                    If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do
                    
                    '~~> Fill the entire range in 1 go
                    .Range(.Cells(aCell.Row, ColA), .Cells(aCell.Row, ColB)).Value = ProcToFind
                Else
                    Exit Do
                End If
            Loop
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

**In Action:**

[image]

Comment: wow thank you!!! This is perfect. I actually have a follow-up question - in my combobox1 for the procedures i actually have them listed out with their string value, for example the first option is "Surgery" and so on. But that string value is associated with the number 1 on my schedule spreadsheet. Is there a way to link the combobox list values with numerical values on the spreadsheet?

Comment: Yes. There is. I would recommend posting a new question for this query.

Comment: okay thanks! just did

Comment: I happen to check your profile. I rarely say this but seems like you are not aware of [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Please note that accepting answers are not mandatory though. The above link is only FYI in case you are not aware :)